# Interpretation of the unix command: ip address

Tags: unix, ip

I have to interprete the result of the unix command: ip address

I'm getting something like this:

```
2: eth-man: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.6.4/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global eth-man
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I already managed to find out some values, but I really have problems to understand what the `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>` part means. Of course i know broadcast and multicast, but what's the meaning here?

Comment: Broadcast is the IP address used when sending a message to all computers on the same LAN. See [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for more information.

Comment: i know that, but why is it written there. Is it a bunch of options?

Comment: Are you asking why it is shown despite `192.168.6.4/24` already implying a broadcast address of `192.168.6.255`? If so than I have no answer other than 'It is easy and it has always been this way'. Which I would find an unsatisfactory answer.

Comment: Those are various options that are available (and enabled) at the [data link level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer).

Comment: but how can I find further descriptions to those options

Comment: Try `man netstat`

Comment: its not netstat, its ip (if there's a difference) and the manual just helps me with the command but not with the result

Comment: What do you want to know? If you look in that manual page, you might see " --groups , -g
       Display multicast group membership information for IPv4 and IPv6."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Broadcast field in the ifconfig command simply means that the interface is able to handle [broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_%28networking%29) packets.   In computer networking, broadcasting refers to transmitting a packet that will be received by every device on the network.   You will usually see the number 255 (decimal) or FF (hexdecimal) when dealing with broadcasts.    If the interface was configured to use a static address instead of getting an address via DHCP, you might not see the broadcast flag set on that interface.   I am not 100% sure on that tho, so don't quote me.

the Multicast field in the ifconfig command means that the adapter can communicate using [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast).  In computer networking, multicast is the delivery of a message or information to a group of destination computers simultaneously in a single transmission from the source. Copies are automatically created in other network elements, such as routers, but only when the topology of the network requires it.

The UP field in the ifconfig command means that the interface listed in the command is currently UP, or is in a state where it can send and receive data.   Just because an interface is up does not necessarily mean it has an IP address assigned to it (if the adapter does not have DHCP enabled, it will need to have an address assigned to it manually).

Unfortunately, I have no idea what LOWER_UP is referring to :\